# Kaggle Notebook NameError

Tags: python, nameerror

Following along with a video on Kaggle, I got a NameError on df.head() stating "df" is not defined.

I tried def but that didn't work either.  Everything was working just fine up to that point.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without some code, it is difficult to know what you've done, but it sounds as though you haven't created the dataframe, something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
print(df.head())
```